# Best quad core, 50Mhz microcontroller with 4MiB RAM

Tags: memory, embedded-systems, microcontroller, arduino

I am that not satisfied with the Arduino's microcontroller's power (but of course satisfied with the I/O on the Arduino mega).

I need:

- at least 4 cores, and
- at least 4MiB of RAM and running at 50mhz (or more), and
- at least 40 I/O pins (that is not analog or PWM).

Which is the best microcontroller for this?

If possible, make sure uploading the program is simple and does not need the chip to be put in some specific programmer. Plus, make it as cheap as possible :).

Comment: Raspberry pi 1GB?

Comment: Oh, ok. i found the Compute Module 4 useful :) ... But even 1 gigabyte of RAM would be a huge overkill. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Plus with at least 40 I/O pins without any external circuitry.